# node_modules/ag-grid/main"' has no exported member 'IHeaderGroup'

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I'm quiet new to angular 4 & trying to use ag-grid from here https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular-angularcli/#gsc.tab=0.

I keep getting errors like below and I couldn't find any links that were helpful:

> node_modules/ag-grid-angular/dist/interfaces.d.ts (1,10): Module
>   '"C:/Use rs/shm/A4/first-app/node_modules/ag-grid/main"' has no
>   exported member 'IHeaderGroup'.
>
> node_modules/ag-grid-angular/dist/interfaces.d.ts (1,24): Module
>   '"C:/Use rs/shm/A4/first-app/node_modules/ag-grid/main"' has no
>   exported member 'IHeaderGroupParams'.
>
> ag-grid-angular/dist/interfaces.d.ts (1,44): Module '"C:/Use
>   rs/shm/A4/first-app/node_modules/ag-grid/main"' has no exported member
>   'IHeader'.

```
//app.module.ts
import {AgGridModule} from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { RedComponentComponent } from './red-component/red-component.component';
import { MyAgGridComponent } from './my-ag-grid/my-ag-grid.component';

        @NgModule({
          declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            SpinnerComponent,
            RedComponentComponent,
            MyAgGridComponent,
          ],
          imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            HttpClientModule, HttpModule,
            FormsModule,
            BrowserAnimationsModule,
            MdButtonModule,
            MdProgressSpinnerModule,
            MdInputModule,
            AgGridModule.withComponents([RedComponentComponent]),
          ],
          exports: [SpinnerComponent],
          providers: [],
          bootstrap: [AppComponent]
        })
        export class AppModule {}
```

package.json

```
"ag-grid-angular": "^12.0.0",
    "ag-grid-ng2": "^8.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
```

Can anyone help me figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two problems with what you have:

- Use either `ag-grid-angular` **or** `ag-grid-ng2`.  `ag-grid-angular` is the dependency to use going forward, it replaces `ag-grid-ng2`
- You need to import as follows:

`import {AgGridModule} from "ag-grid-angular/main";`

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it, it was ag-grid-ng2.